# Selective (or partial) sorting of vector elements in R

Tags: r

I have a vector called `myvec<- c("B","C","D","A")`. I want to position `C` and `D` elements first and second then `B` and `A`.Thus the result should be `C,D,B,A`. How can we get this done in R?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To just bring `"C"` and `"D"` to the front:

```
myvec <- c("B","C","D","A")

myvec[order(!myvec %in% c('C', 'D'))]
#[1] "C" "D" "B" "A"
```

To give a complete ordering:

```
myvec <- c("B","C","D","A")

order.vec <- c('C', 'D', 'B', 'A')

myvec[order(match(myvec, order.vec))]
# [1] "C" "D" "B" "A"
```

Example with a different input vector:

```
myvec <- sample(myvec, 20, T)

myvec[order(match(myvec, order.vec))]
# [1] "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "B" "B" "B" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A"
```

Comment: Why so many repititions? `"C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "D" "B" "B" "B" "A" "A" "A" "A" "A`?

Comment: The repetitions only happen with `myvec` defined differently. I was just giving another example of why you might use this method, because in your example there's really no need. You could just type `y <- c('C', 'D', 'B', 'A')`

Comment: Additionally, I don't want to type the whole order of the vector. `order.vec <- c('C', 'D', 'B', 'A')` this not what I want.

Comment: I just want to type the two elements `"C","D"` that I want to bring forward. Is there an efficient way?

Comment: The result should be `C,D,B,A`, but I have millions of elements and just want to change the position of fifty something elements. It's cumbersome to type and reorder all elements over again. I think the best way to do is using `grepl`.

Comment: See my edit for how to bring e.g. just  `"C"` and `"D"` to the front.

Answer (score 2):

You can using `factor`

```
 sort(factor(myvec <- sample(myvec, 20, T),c('C', 'D', 'B', 'A')))
 [1] C C C D D D D D D B B B B B B A A A A A
Levels: C D B A
```

Answer (score 2):

I generally use setdiff() for when I want to remove elements from a vector

```
myvec <- c("B","C","D","A")
put_first <- c("C", "D")
new_vec <- c(put_first, setdiff(myvec, put_first))
new_vec
# [1] "C" "D" "B" "A"
```

Edited
If you want it to allow for multiples in the data.

```
myvec <- c("B", "B","C", "C","D", "D", "A", "A")
put_first <- c("C", "D")
new_vec <- c(myvec[myvec %in% put_first], myvec[!myvec %in% put_first])
new_vec
# [1] "C" "C" "D" "D" "B" "B" "A" "A"
```

Comment: Yes, but the original post did not specify that as a requirement.